# how does Google Doc get the fonts list installed on PC/Mac

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fonts

I use Chinese language, when I install a new Chinese font, reopen my google doc page, the new font will show in the font list. I want to know how google do this. I search this question in google, there is only one method that using flex to fetch the system fonts, but I close the flash plugin of chrome and retry, It also works fine! And it also works fine on SAFARI, how did Google Doc do this?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to detect what fonts are installed in the system in vanilla JS without any flash or such.

http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/